# How to configure Caucho Resin's Java classpath to the system's library directory

Tags: java, classpath, resin

I have a folder, '/var/unity/conf' with some properties files in it, and I'd like the Caucho's Resin JVM to have that directory on the classpath.

What is the best way to modifiy resin.conf so that Resin knows to add this directory to the classpath?

Answer (score 3):

With Resin 3.1.6 and above, use

```
<server-default>
    ...
    <jvm-classpath>/var/unity/conf/...</jvm-classpath>
    ...
</server-default>
```

(I know, very late to the game, I was searching for the answer to this myself and found this post here, as well as the solution, so thought I'd add back to the collective).

Answer (score 1):

cd %RESIN_HOME%/lib | 
ln -s /var/unity/conf/....

Comment: This was the only way I have found to get it to work.  I was hoping there was another way to do it.  
I think one problem with this method is it won't work on Windows.